# how to get changeset list of current build in Jenkins

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, changeset

Am looking for a solution where I can get change set of current build from last successful build.

We are using git hub as SCM

I want to get the change set redirected to a text file, where I can further perform operations on the change set content

I tried
git diff --name-only $GIT_COMMIT $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT

but of no use.
Its ending up with error can not access commit id.

Answer (score 6):

For your use case, you can use Jenkins global variables. To retrieve the changed files from current build you can use this one:

```
currentBuild.changeSets
```

To do the same but for the previous build:

```
currentBuild.previousBuild.changeSets
```

The full reference is [here](https://ci.jenkins.io/pipeline-syntax/globals).